# Python: Filter out rows from result set of pyodbc.row when row contains string

Tags: python

I have not been able to find an answer to this seemingly straightforward filter process.

I have a result set of table names for a simple odbc query and I want to filter that result set anything that contains the prefix 'wer_'

```
*Some pyodbc connection code*

cursor.execute(<SQL statement which gets the list of tables>)
results = cursor.fetchall()
results = [key for key in results if str(key.name).str.contains('wer_')]
```

^ I've tried various methods around this but so far no dice. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be fairly straight forward in the end. It seems pyodbc.row has an attribute of name which you can compare against

```
*Some pyodbc connection code*

cursor.execute(<SQL statement which gets the list of tables>)
results = cursor.fetchall()
results = [key for key in results if 'wer_' not in key.name]
```

I hope this helps somebody in the future!